# Android table layout

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

In my app i'am setting each table row in code.

**Row setting code**

```
            final TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
            row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_nw);
            row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 150));
            row.setMinimumHeight(100);
            //tr.addView(view);
            String[] colText = {"" + outlet_name, "" + outlet_qty, "" + outlet_price, "" + outlet_tot};
            for (String text : colText) {
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                //EditText ev=new EditText(this);

                tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,150));
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setTextSize(14);

            //    tv.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt("#D3D3D3"));

                tv.setText(text);

                row.addView(tv);

            }
            tableLayout.addView(row);
```

in this row i want the second cell,that is 'outlet_qty' as edit text and all other as textview.each of the 'colText' array variables gets its value from Sqlite..
is there any way to achievethis?pls help

Comment: As you know outlet_qty column position is 1 in array so you can use a static condition for this directly. Check answer given by readyandroid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all is to manage TextView and EditText for a specific column number. you can manage data input from sqlite as how you are doing as same.

```
final TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
        row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_nw);
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 150));
        row.setMinimumHeight(100);
        //tr.addView(view);
        String[] colText = {"" + outlet_name, "" + outlet_qty, "" + outlet_price, "" + outlet_tot};
        for (int i = 0; i < colText.length; i++) {
            EditText ev = new EditText(this);
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            if (i == 1) {//For outlet_qty
                ev.setId(i);
                ev.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 150));
                ev.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                ev.setTextSize(14);
                //    ev.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt("#D3D3D3"));
                ev.setText(colText[i]);
                ev.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        if (s.length() > 0) {
                            ((TextView) row.findViewById(Integer.valueOf(3))).setText(s.toString().trim());
                        } else {
                            ((TextView) row.findViewById(Integer.valueOf(3))).setText("");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                });
                row.addView(ev);
            } else {
                tv.setId(i);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 150));
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setTextSize(14);
                //    tv.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt("#D3D3D3"));
                tv.setText(colText[i]);
                row.addView(tv);
            }
        }
        tableLayout.addView(row);
```

Comment: is there any way to update the 'outlet_tot' textview in response to edittext value change..i have done the 'ev.addTextChangedListener' part and calculated the total amount to be displayed and stored it in sqlite db..on restarting the app the new total is shown in 'outlet_tot' textview.how to update textview value in 'ev.addTextChangedListener' so that it is shown without restarting app ?

Comment: check updated answer for text change listener in edittext. If it works for you then please upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this. In the for Loop where you iterate over the columns we check if the colum is outlet_qty. if we match the outlet_qty column we add a Edit text. And for all other we add the text views.

```
            final TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
            row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_nw);
            row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 150));
            row.setMinimumHeight(100);
            //tr.addView(view);
            String[] colText = {"" + outlet_name, "" + outlet_qty, "" + outlet_price, "" + outlet_tot};
            // iterate over colunms
            for (String text : colText) {

                // add edit text for outlet_qty column
                if(text.equals(outlet_qty))
                {
                    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
                    // do stuff with the edit text like prefilling data etc
                    row.addView(tv);
                }
                // for all others we add text views
                else
                {
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                //EditText ev=new EditText(this);

                tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,150));
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setTextSize(14);

            //    tv.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt("#D3D3D3"));

                tv.setText(text);

                row.addView(tv);
                }

            }
            tableLayout.addView(row);
```